# Button click in one form perform action in another form

Tags: forms, events, multiple-forms

How do I make an event in one form perform in another.  I have one form (New Well form) with 2 textboxes, a combobox, and a button.  This is called whenever a new progress bar is needed on the main form (Stage Tally Main).  Whenever I fill in the information on the New well and hit the button I want Stage tally Main to add a progress bar with the information from the textboxes and combobox.  How can I make a button on New Well form add a progressbar on Stage Tally Main?

Answer (score 0):

its actually really easy.  If you have a series of code you would like to perform on form 2, then you can just put: Public Sub some_code() on form 1. and in form 2, under button click, or form load, or whatever you can say form.some_code() and call the series of code.  Ill create a better example here:

Notice only in the below code the new well form that is loaded by a menu item and that on down is a public sub called go_Progess_bar().  the code describes creating a progress bar at a certain position, blah blah blah.  Basically all of the code I want performed on this form in another form i can initialize with a simple: public sub some_name()

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub NewWellToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NewWellToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Dim NewWell As New NewWellForm()
    NewWell.ShowDialog()

End Sub

Public Sub go_Progress_Bar()
    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each ctrl In Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is ProgressBar Then
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

    Dim NumProgressBar As String = Convert.ToString(i)

    Dim pBar As New ProgressBar()

    pBar.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(20, 50 * (2 * i + 1))

    pBar.Name = "progressBar" + NumProgressBar

    pBar.Width = 1200

    pBar.Height = 30

    Dim CrewAndWell As New Label

    CrewAndWell.Name = CrewSelection + WellSelection

    CrewAndWell.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(20, 50 * (2 * i + 1) - 20)

    CrewAndWell.Width = 100

    CrewAndWell.Height = 20

    CrewAndWell.Text = CrewSelection + ": " + WellSelection

    Controls.Add(CrewAndWell)

    Controls.Add(pBar)
End Sub
```

New well form code is below, which represents form2.  Ignore everything else except the button click event.  When the button is clicked go_Progress_Bar is called by form1.go_Progress_Bar() and the code executes on form1.  It is so simple a caveman could do it.

Public Class NewWellForm

```
Private Sub NewWellForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(CrewList.ToArray())
End Sub
Private Sub AddWell_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddWell.Click
    CrewSelection = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
    WellSelection = WellNameText.Text
    Form1.go_Progress_Bar()
    Close()
End Sub
```

End Class